# Yelp API ios getting a larger image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, yelp

I am currently using the Yelp API for my project, and I need to get the image of a business to use as a background, displayed in a UIImageView. However, all the pictures are too small from the pictures obtained, so the background is blurry. I use this code to obtain the current business images:

```
[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[businessDict objectForKey:@"image_url"]]]];
```

Is there anyway to obtain a larger image?

Comment: What is the image URL?

Comment: The image_url is a string that yelp provides, which I am turning into data for UIImage

Comment: Usually that image url ends with `m.jpg` or `ms.jpg` which returns a medium size image. If that is the case, try `l.jpg` for larger image.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace the filename at the end of the image URL with `o.jpg` and you'll get up to 1000×1000 pixels. Other sizes are:

- `s.jpg`: up to 40×40
- `ss.jpg`: 40×40 square
- `m.jpg`: up to 100×100
- `ms.jpg`: 100×100 square
- `l.jpg`: up to 600×400
- `ls.jpg`: 250×250 square
- `o.jpg`: up to 1000×1000
- `348s.jpg`: 348×348 square

Comment: thanks! i don't know why you don't have this marked as right answer!