# How to request larger images from Yelp API?

Tags: api, yelp

Is there a way to request larger images from Yelp?

The current response from their server is 100x100px.

Here's a sample:
http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/ehZk1zXTE5xof4d2fcGLeQ/ms.jpg

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yelp API ios getting a larger image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965691/yelp-api-ios-getting-a-larger-image)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran into this a little while back.

You can replace the "ms" in .../ms.jpg with "l" for large, "s" for small, and you can use "o" for original, which will return the largest image.

Try the original: http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/ehZk1zXTE5xof4d2fcGLeQ/o.jpg

Best of luck!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. For future readers, there is some additional information on a different answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965691/yelp-api-ios-getting-a-larger-image